# Where are orderline_notes in Odoo 10.0 POS Restaurant saved in the database?

Tags: odoo, pos

I am trying to get the orderline_notes at a tree view. but it seems that the field doesn't exist. Do you have any idea where a note added in the Restaurant POS goes to after closing the POS ticket?

I have tried iface_orderline_notes as well as orderline_notes and export all the fields from an order without finding the added comments.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tree string="POS Orders" decoration-info="state == 'draft'" decoration-muted="state in ('done','cancel')" create="0">
                <field name="orderline_notes"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems they aren't stored anywhere except in JavaScript and therefor only in the one Session of the PoS.

Comment: That's what I guessed but thanks for confirming. Thanks.